# where do i put my DB code when opening window in Netbeans platform?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a Netbeans Platform application. Upon opening the main frame, i want to populate a GUI table with elements pulled from a database.

Where is the best place to have this code? I have tried the **componentOpened()** method but I get a thread deadlock. Even using **invokeLater()** I run into threading issues.

```
    @Override
public void componentOpened() {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            List<UserBO> al = UserDelegate.getInstance().getUsers();

            for (UserBO u : al) {

                System.out.println("User " + u);
            }
        }
    });

    // TODO add custom code on component opening
}
```

The above code always causes thread deadlocks. I am not sure if componentOpened() the right method is to have this code.

Comment: why not have separate SQL class that interacts with SQL ?

Comment: it is in a seperate class (in a singelton delegate per se)

Comment: Then a code / stacktraces would help us understand what is happening

Comment: difficult if you have a thread deadlock

Comment: Use swingWorker, Timer or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

Solution. Put the DB reading code in the constructor of the component (ie "Top Component"). Then use the Netbeans RequestProcessor.

```
    public EditorTopComponent() {
    initComponents();
    setName(Bundle.CTL_EditorTopComponent());
    setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_EditorTopComponent());

    RequestProcessor.getDefault().post(new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            List<UserBO> al = UserDelegate.getInstance().getUsers();

            System.out.println("Users dude ");

            for (UserBO u : al) {
                System.out.println("User " + u);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This now works